# Get nested custom fields JSON Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

Im having a bit of a problem with a JSON I get in Objective C

this is the JSON:

```
 {
        "id": 264,
        "type": "products",
        "slug": "dali",
        "url": "http://localhost/?products=dali",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Dali",
        "title_plain": "Dali",
        "content": "",
        "excerpt": "",
        "date": "2014-03-25 15:47:16",
        "modified": "2014-04-04 15:52:52",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 26,
                "slug": "juices-2",
                "title": "Juices",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 1
            }
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "arturocalvo",
            "name": "arturocalvo",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "arturocalvo",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "custom_fields": {
            "tipo_de_producto": [
                "bebida"
            ],
            "tipo_de_bebida": [
                "jugo"
            ],
            "product_0_sucursal": [
                "2"
            ],
            "product": [
                "1"
            ],
            "product_0_sizes_0_size": [
                "s"
            ],
            "product_0_sizes_1_size": [
                "m"
            ],
            "product_0_sizes_2_size": [
                "l"
            ],
            "product_0_sizes": [
                "3"
            ],
            "product_0_prices_0_price": [
                "20"
            ],
            "product_0_prices_1_price": [
                "25"
            ],
            "product_0_prices_2_price": [
                "30"
            ],
            "product_0_prices": [
                "3"
            ]
        }
    }
```

when Im mapping it with ResKit, I want to store the 3 different sizes in an array I have in the class Below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "ProductPrice.h"

@class Categories, ProductPrice;

@interface AllProducts : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * productType;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * locationId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * sizes;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet * productCategoryId;

@end
```

this is the Object mapping code:

```
//Products Mapping
RKObjectMapping *productsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[AllProducts class]];
[productsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"title": @"name",
                                                      @"custom_fields.product_0_sucursal": @"locationId",
                                                      @"custom_fields.tipo_de_producto": @"productType",                                                          
                                                      @"categories.id": @"productCategoryId"
                                                      }];
```

the problem Im having is that the keys of the JSON came with 3 different numbers, product_0_sizes_0_size and then in goes from 0 to 2, I don't know what to put in the mapping code, can anyone help me?, thanks in advance

Comment: So the keys are static, but you don't know how many there will be without reading `product_0_sizes`? And there could be lots? And you have no chance of changing the JSON?

Comment: exactly, unfortunately the JSON comes from wordpress, and I cant change it, and it could be 10 sizes o more, so, there is a way to handle that?

Comment: You know, you could just write code.  It would be faster than trying to contort ResKit to do what it doesn't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your situation is a bit rubbish (due to the unpleasant JSON). If you had the option you should change that.

As you can't, I think the best option is to create a dynamic mapping that you use as the mapping of the response descriptor. That mapping returns a mapping created from what you currently have with additions made in a loop based on the content of `product_0_sizes` to generate the source key paths.

Now, things get more unpleasant as you can only have one mapping to each destination key, and you obviously have multiple source keys that you want to merge to a single destination key.

I'd try abuse `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` to work around that. If you create your destination keys as `appendSize0`, `appendSize1`, ... without creating those properties on the class then `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` should be called on your destination class for each source key that is mapped. In your implementation of `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` you can extract the supplied values and append them to your true `sizes` array.

*(Note: I haven't directly tried this but it should work. There is a risk of issues with type introspection for data type mutation...)*

*(Note: Your implementation of `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` should call `super` if you receive a key that doesn't start with `appendSize`)*

Abusing `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` is certainly minimal code. Alternative would be to add a whole heap of properties that you can map into, but that's not very nice or flexible.